Как определить последнее активное EditorWindow?
У меня одновременно открывается несколько модальных окон EditorWindow. Есть необходимость знать в какой последовательности они открывались, или хотя бы при смене фокуса окна  отлавливать это. Конечно у окна есть 'OnFocus', но к сожалению он срабатывает и когда просто мышь оказывается над окном которое сейчас не активно и доступа к нему нет.
Может кто знает способ?

В документации у EditorWindow не так много static, через который мы взаимодействуем с другими окнами. Всего 5 методов и 2 свойства, и по focusedWindow можно отслеживать.

Изначально я так и пробовал, но почему то проверка 'focusedWindow == this' давала true с любым диалоговым окном, в том числе не активным. Не стал разбираться почему. 'Equals()' спасает, но при этом у Unity3D есть такая нехорошая фишка, что если одновременно открыть несколько модальных окон, он позволяет между ними спокойно переключаться. Создать как в windows модального диалога блокирующего диалог из которого он вызывается у меня пока не получилось.
